# How to declare 2D dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

How to declare a 2D array in which the rows are dynamic but the rows length are fixed? Is there any way to do it without both row and rows length are dynamic?

P.S. I can't use STL containers or class string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for this.

`std::vector` is a dynamic-length array.

`std::array` is a fixed-length array, used as

```cpp
array<int, 20> arr;
arr[10] = 42;
array<int, 20> anotherArr = arr; // copied here, as opposed to C arrays

int oldStyleArr[20];
oldStyleArr[10] = 42;
// int newStyleArr[20] = oldStyleArr; // error here
```

It is a convenient wrapper over the C-style array, and it provides value semantics and various conveniece methods like `size()`.

So you can create `array<vector<int>, 20>` for an array of 20 dynamic vectors of `int`s or `vector<array<int, 20>>` for a dynamic vector of fixed-length arrays.

**UPD:** `std::array` works only with array bounds known at compile-time. If your array bounds are known only at runtime, you still can use `std::vector`'s constructor from size and (optional) element:

```cpp
int rowCount, columnCount;
cin >> rowCount >> columnCount;
using Row = vector<int>;

// create `vector` of `rowCount` rows,
// where each row is `vector` of `columnCount` ints
vector<Row> arr2d(rowCount, Row(columnCount));
```

However, that's not the most efficient solution because each row is allocated separately. You can solve this with a little wrapper over one-dimensional `vector`:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Vector2D {
public:
  Vector2D(int rows, int cols)
    : data(rows*cols)
    , rows(rows)
    , cols(cols) {}

  int rowCount() const { return rows; }
  int columnCount() const { return cols; }

  T&       get(int r, int c)       { return data[r*cols + c]; }
  T const& get(int r, int c) const { return data[r*cols + c]; }

  void addRow() {
    data.resize(cols*(rows + 1));
  }

// ...

private:
  vector<T> data;
  int rows;
  int cols;
};
```

Comment: This works if the width is known at compile type. But it won't work for a real 2D array with rows and columns only known at runtime

Comment: @phuclv Dynamic arrays like `vector`s will perfectly fit in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector` for dynamic range arrays. You would want to instantiate a vector of arrays to achieve this.

Comment: you mean std::vector (without uppercase). I think you have to explain more for the OP, also given example

Comment: You are right, that was a bit short. Yuri already gave a more extensive answer so I won't duplicate it but I will try to do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a 1D array and **calculate the index yourself** like how compilers generate accesses to a multidimensional array. Each row has `width` items, so the `[x][y]` element will have the index `x*width + y`

```
template<typename T>
class twoD
{
    const int width;
    const int height;
    T* data;

    twoD(int w, int h) : width(w), height(h)
    {
        data = new T[width*height];
    }

    ~twoD()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    T& at(int x, int y)
    {
        return data[x*width + y];
    }

    T const& at(int x, int y) const
    {
        return data[x*width + y];
    }
}

twoD myArray(4, 8);
myArray.at(2, 3) = 5;
myArray.at(4, 5) = 6 - myArray.at(2, 3);
```

The same method can be used to access multidimensional arrays in any degree

Comment: @Strick it's only a very simple example and not a full-blown solution. I'm not solving everything in OP's likely homework

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably: `std::vector<std::array<int, 20>> arr;`

However, if STL containers are not an option you might need to implement the container yourself. A linked list is probably the easiest to implement.